# Python parameters SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, parameters, syntax-error

I have a lot of bash related programming skills, but my Python skills are lacking. I can't seem to do something as simple as having two parameters for a user to input images.

The code is supposed to take two images from separate parameters, and then run the "match_color" function with them before outputting a new image.

Here is my code:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
import argparse 

@click.argument('-target_image', type=click.Path(exists=True))
@click.argument('-source_image', type=click.Path(exists=True))
#Specify the name of the output file.
#@click.argument('-out_file', type=click.Path(exists=True))



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args.parser.parse_args
args = SimpleNamespace(**kwargs)
target_img = Image.open(args.target_image)
source_img = Image.open(args.source_image)




def match_color(target_img, source_img, mode='pca', eps=1e-5):
    '''
    Matches the colour distribution of the target image to that of the source image
    using a linear transform.
    Images are expected to be of form (w,h,c) and float in [0,1].
    Modes are chol, pca or sym for different choices of basis.
    '''
    mu_t = target_img.mean(0).mean(0)
    t = target_img - mu_t
    t = t.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)
    Ct = t.dot(t.T) / t.shape[1] + eps * eye(t.shape[0])
    mu_s = source_img.mean(0).mean(0)
    s = source_img - mu_s
    s = s.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)
    Cs = s.dot(s.T) / s.shape[1] + eps * eye(s.shape[0])
    if mode == 'chol':
        chol_t = np.linalg.cholesky(Ct)
        chol_s = np.linalg.cholesky(Cs)
        ts = chol_s.dot(np.linalg.inv(chol_t)).dot(t)
    if mode == 'pca':
        eva_t, eve_t = np.linalg.eigh(Ct)
        Qt = eve_t.dot(np.sqrt(np.diag(eva_t))).dot(eve_t.T)
        eva_s, eve_s = np.linalg.eigh(Cs)
        Qs = eve_s.dot(np.sqrt(np.diag(eva_s))).dot(eve_s.T)
        ts = Qs.dot(np.linalg.inv(Qt)).dot(t)
    if mode == 'sym':
        eva_t, eve_t = np.linalg.eigh(Ct)
        Qt = eve_t.dot(np.sqrt(np.diag(eva_t))).dot(eve_t.T)
        Qt_Cs_Qt = Qt.dot(Cs).dot(Qt)
        eva_QtCsQt, eve_QtCsQt = np.linalg.eigh(Qt_Cs_Qt)
        QtCsQt = eve_QtCsQt.dot(np.sqrt(np.diag(eva_QtCsQt))).dot(eve_QtCsQt.T)
        ts = np.linalg.inv(Qt).dot(QtCsQt).dot(np.linalg.inv(Qt)).dot(t)
    matched_img = ts.reshape(*target_img.transpose(2,0,1).shape).transpose(1,2,0)
    matched_img += mu_s
    matched_img[matched_img>1] = 1
    matched_img[matched_img<0] = 0
    return matched_img

 matched_img.save('out.png')
```

When trying to run the code, I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/ubuntu/Transfer$ python3 linear-color-transfer.py -target_image fig4_style3.jpg -source_image fig4_content.jpg
  File "linear-color-transfer.py", line 11
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/ubuntu/Transfer$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@click` command should be used with `functions`

your code should be like:

```
@click.argument('-target_image', type=click.Path(exists=True))
@click.argument('-source_image', type=click.Path(exists=True))
def match_color(target_img, source_img, mode='pca', eps=1e-5):
    #body
```